# Вызов функции после завершения построения DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Как правильно вызвать какую-то функцию, когда DOM готов?
Допустим, мне нужно вызвать функцию main, которая ничего не принимает.
Какой из этих трёх вариантов более корректен?

1. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);`
2. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main());`
3. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       main();
    });`

Все три варианта chrome нормально переваривает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый или третий. Во втором, происходит вызов функции сразу, а ее результат пытается повешать на EventListener

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что 3-ий вариант для замыканий используют?

Comment: Да, для замыкания

Comment: Дмитрий,  Вы кое-что забыли сделать)

Comment: @Дмытрык, что? :)